# Multiple select statement in sql(impala)

Tags: sql

So I a trying write an sql query that will retrieve values of different locations in the data and put them in a table. I have only heard about nested select statements but not "parallel" select. An example query I come up with is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE TMP AS

SELECT location,value

From table

WHERE location = "A", location = "B", location = "C"
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you say what you want the query to do in English? Is it gonna be WHERE location is A OR B OR C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want select the rows with location equal to A or B or C could be you   need  an IN clause

```
CREATE TABLE TMP AS
SELECT location,value
From table
WHERE location IN ("A",  "B",  "C")
```